# Creating an inbuild shutter in you app

Tags: ios

Hi i would like to create this kind of shutter in my application from bottom to top, does anyone know any tutorials or any thing online. If you give me any suggestion that would be great. I tried looked into the Cocoa Controls but not be able to find anything similar.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you didn't searched good enough.

Any way here it is : [Pullable View (Notification Center style)](https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView)